# urllib2.URLError While trying to read html

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read html file with `pandas`

I have the following code :

```
state_names = pd.read_html('https://www.factmonster.com/us/postal-information/state-abbreviations-and-state-postal-codes')
```

However running this code gives me the following error

> urllib2.URLError: urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)>

This is the case for any other website other than wikipedia 
for example running this works perfectly

```
state_names = pd.read_html('https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states')
```

Any solution to get html pages other than `wikipedia`?

Comment: Your code works for me. Have you tried `state_names = pd.read_html('http://www.factmonster.com/us/postal-information/state-abbreviations-and-state-postal-codes', header=0)` (http instead of https) or `state_names = pd.read_html('https://www.factmonster.com/us/postal-information/state-abbreviations-and-state-postal-codes', header=0, flavor='bs4')` (different engine).

Comment: @NielsHenkens thanks for the suggestion but it still shows me the error while loading from that specific website, along with this error `File "\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 987, in read_html
    displayed_only=displayed_only)`.
did u run the code with that specific website?

Comment: Yes, I tried that specific site. Have you tried updating your pandas library? Since the error points to that part? And does the answer below work for you? Otherwise the problem might lie in you urllib2 installation.

Comment: @NielsHenkens just update all my libraries, yet i get the same error. I like to note that some of the websites like wikipedias do work with the same code, so im assuming some issue with the request and not the libraries itself

Answer (score 0):

Try this method..It will give you all the HTML data.

```
import urllib2  

url = 'https://www.factmonster.com/us/postal-information/state-abbreviations-and-state-postal-codes'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url=url) 
html = response.read()
data = pd.read_html(html) 
print data
```

Comment: And does updating urllib2 help?